# Is $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ a sign-preserving transformation of $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions, transformation

Here are what I learned: a transformation is just a real function $F$. If a real function $f(x)$ is transformed, then $f(x)$ becomes "$F[f(x)]$", which is another real function.

Assume $g(x)>0$. $x$ is a variable.

Question：

1. Is $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ a transformation of $f(x)$?
2. Is $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ a sign-preserving transformation of $f(x)$?

My answer:

1. $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ can not equal to $F[f(x)]$, so $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is not a transformation.
2. Since $g(x)>0$,  $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is indeed a sign-preserving transformation.

So the  answers seem to contradict each other: how can a sign-preserving transformation not a transformation?? I am very very confused.

---

For Q1 we might be able to play a trick like $F(y)=g(f^{-1}(y))\cdot y$. But $f^{-1}$ can be ill-defined.

Comment: It may also depend on your assumptions and the precise definition of what you understand of a transformation. For example if $g(x) = $constant, then it is definitely a transformation of $f(x)$.  But to me it is not clear whether $x$ is fixed or variable. Surely, for each fixed $x$ you have up there a sign preserving transformation of $f(x)$. But if you define a transformation of $f$ to be of the form $F[f]$, then it might be a different story, like you said. You could introduce your trick as the definition for your transformation and then specify a domain (all invertible $f$) of definition.

Comment: I just would like to mention that my above comment makes not much sense. I ran afoul of what is meant here and then I drew some wrong conclusions. The answer of @Joseph Camacho below is very nice.

Comment: Without knowing your definitions, I would remark that it doesn’t make much sense for there to exist a sign-preserving transformation that doesn’t satisfy the conditions to also be called a transformation.

Comment: @Numa $x$ is a variable.

Comment: Why the tag "geometry" ???

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of "transformation" isn't informative.  It's just notation.  A more concrete definition would be something like:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be spaces of functions.  (E.g. $X$ could be all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, and $Y$ could be all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$.)  A *transformation* is a function $F : X \to Y$, where evaluation is typically written $F[f]$ (with square brackets) instead of $F(f)$ (with parentheses).

If you use this (or other sane definitions), then you'll quickly see there is no contradiction.  Yes, the map $f \mapsto f\cdot g$ is a transformation, and yes, it preserves sign if $g > 0$.